# Passing an Array with Objects to another function in GAS

Tags: arrays, callback, google-apps-script, google-forms

Just to give you a little background on my question:
I am creating a form in Google App Script using the UI Services and I am storing specific calendar events in a dataArray. So the event **object** is stored in the array. I want to pass this array to the submit function but can't figure out how to go about this because :

1. I can't add it as a callback element (because it isn't a widget)
2. I can't store the event object in a widget (i.e. a listbox, etc) and then add that widget as a callback element.

Here is a brief sample of what I am trying to do:

```
var cal= CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
var event= cal.getEvents(new Date("June 16, 2013 PST"),
                               new Date("July 22, 2013 PST"));
var specific = new Array;
for( var j=0; j<event.length;j++){
specific.push(event[j]);
//This stores the events in the specific variable
//I want to send this variable (w/ the data) to another function on submit
```

I would appreciate any suggestions you can lend me.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you include (a minimal version) of your code in the question?

Comment: Why don't you store the event id  instead?With this id  you can get back the event and do whatever you want with it...

Comment: I did this, I don't think you can access the event and grab the day and time of the event with just the id

Comment: @Sergeinsas How would I access the event title, start time, and date with just the id? Maybe I am just unaware of the functionality.

Comment: You can use `getEventSeriesById(iCalId)` and get an event that has all parameters available with event methods even if it's identified as an event serie, it doesn't change anything from the user point of view.

Comment: if you don't want to do that, you could also simply store the id and while you read the events again using the same start/end time you can check if an event correspond to the saved ID in a loop... if a match is found with the right ID you are sure it's the right event.

Comment: Awesome I will try the second solution out!

Comment: Is there a reason why you accepted /unaccepted the answer below?

Comment: I think I accepted it. I didn't explicitly use the strategy you suggested but it pointed me in the right direction so I thought I would give credit where credit is due :)

Comment: On another note, do you know how to display a pop-up message box in the browser (the script is hosted on a website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a complement to the answer I gave in the comments : *"you could also simply store the id and while you read the events again using the same start/end time you can check if an event correspond to the saved ID in a loop... if a match is found with the right ID you are sure it's the right event"*

Here is a piece of code I use to modify/update/delete calendar events using their ID as reference. This code is used to delete specific events selected from the spreadsheet, the code to modify events is roughly the same, at least it uses the same ID checking.

```
  ...
  var cal = CalendarApp.openByName(calName);
  if (cal) {
    var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(date_deb), new Date(date_fin),{max: 4000}); // stocke tt ds une variable array
    var sel= sh.getRange(6,1,sh.getLastRow()-5, 10).getValues();// read data in the SS
    for(e=0;e<events.length;++e){
      var delFlag = false;
      var ID = events[e].getId(); 
      for(n=0;n<sel.length;++n){ 
        if ((sel[n][8] == "x"||sel[n][8] == "X")&&sel[n][9]==ID){ // the ID here is stored in the spreadsheet in column J and I use a 'X' marker to select which event should be deleted
          delFlag = true;
          sh.getRange(n+6,9,1,2).setBackgroundColor('#ff5500');
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
          Logger.log('FLAG '+ e);
          break;
        }
      }
        if(delFlag){
          try{
          var toDelete = events[e].deleteEvent(); 
          ++todel; 
          delFlag = false;
          Logger.log('event deleted : '+sel[n][1]);
          }catch(Err){Logger.log('Event from a serie already deleted from another occurence')}
      }
    }
  }
  var msg = todel + " événement(s) effacé(s) dans l'Agenda '"+calName+"'";
  ss.toast("Effacement terminé", msg, 3);
  ...
```